# Update $routeParams and refresh the page with new parameter

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I think the title indicates what I want to achieve quite well. As an example, say, I have a route parameter:

```
$routeProvider.when("/:id/page", {
            controller: "pageCtrl",
            templateUrl: "page.html"
        });
```

And in the controller, I want to change it and refresh the page. Is there such a way? For example:

```
$routeParams.id=12;
$route.reload();
```

Thanks for any help in advance...

---

Note:

Currently I use this way:

```
var pathArray = $location.path().split("/");
pathArray[1] = 12;
$location.path(pathArray.join("/"));
```

But I'm looking for a more generic way.

Comment: Have you considered using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)? ;p

Comment: i need a answer for this question......

Comment: I couldn't see this in the docs, could you provide a direct link to this feature...